# cpu.stat metrics in a pod are zeroed when CPU limits are removed

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, cpu, limit

I know that the topic for CPU limits and cfs quota has received a lot of attention since 2017 and in a multiple threads on kubernetes, a kernal fix was issued and much more. I’m hoping to find some solace here so i’m quite puzzled and would like help on the subject.

We’ve come across something we really cant find any reason for and maybe someone here knows.
We are checking out some throttling issue and came across the notion of either having cpu limits vs no cpu limits set.
as such, we decided to test both and see what best works for us.
We took a pod and removed its limits - but what we found out was - that now the period, quota and stat are empty

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_quota_us
-1

cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_period_us
100000

cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.stat
nr_periods 0
nr_throttled 0
throttled_time 0
```

When we ran htop within the pod we clearly saw cpu being used, when we checked /proc/stat - its full of data about the cpu.

The metrics in grafana - container_cpu_usage_seconds_total - shows metrics.
yet ‘container_cpu_cfs_throttled_periods_total’ and ‘container_cpu_cfs_periods_total’ - are empty for that same pod

when we put limits back in, those fields and files are populated.
we’re quite phased by this, because it means that we cannot monitor any potential throttling on pods that dont have any limits on the CPU.

or is there some other method to monitor throttling when those values are zeroed?

is this by design? has anyone come across this?

any input would be appreciated, thanks

Even though CPU limits in the pod are removed, we still expect to monitor throttling period on any level as some pods may have limits and some on, there's the OS and kernel.

**edit
I'm well aware of any and all recommendations relating to CPU and limits. My question is how would you monitor throttling if the metrics that assist in monitoring are statically 0? As i mentioned, the metrics for that not populated when you remove the limits.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is normal behavior that CPU Limits in the pod causes throttling.If you configure a CPU limit in K8s it will set period and quota. If a process running in a container reaches the limit it is preempted and has to wait for the next period. It is throttled. **So this is the effect, which you are experiencing which results in throttling as 0 when the CPU limit is removed.**

The period and quota algorithm should not be considered to be a CPU limit, where processes are unthrottled, if not reached. The behavior is confusing, and also a K8s issue exists for this in [github.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67577) The recommendation given [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51135) is to not set CPU limits for pods that shouldn't be throttled.

You actually don't want CPU limits in most cases because they prevent pods from using spare resources. There are [Kubernetes maintainers](https://home.robusta.dev/blog/stop-using-cpu-limits) on the record saying you shouldn't use CPU limits and should only set requests. This way pods are free to use spare CPU instead of letting the CPU stay idle.

In contrast, even if you remove this pod’s CPU limit, other pods are still guaranteed the CPU they requested. The CPU limit only affects how spare CPU is distributed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but im more concerned how to monitor pods without any cpu limits, since as i stated, i removed the limits and the usual throttling metrics now result in 0.

Comment: @DannyTeller, If the CPU limits are removed,there will be no throttling and the metrics will be 0 for which you cannot monitor the pods if there is no throttling effect.

Comment: that's exactly what im getting at. If you have no pod metrics because cpu limit has been removed. How would you circumvent in order to know that you have throttling. Right know i can think of node cpu utilization - if theres no idle cpu and its almost always utilized and pod http latency is slow. Probably then you would have throttling